# Popover do not show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popover, bootstrap-popover

Popover do not show fully when hovering button. It is going for inside a screen.

I refer the internet why popover hidden by screen, But not yet getting correct fix.

Please refer the below sample

http://jsfiddle.net/8o48q5ej/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="tips my-tip2" data-placement="left" data-content="Second Popover content">
       Second Div Content
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {


    $('.wrapper2').popover({
        selector: '.my-tip2',
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
});
```

Comment: swap `data-placement="left"` for `data-placement="right"`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon No I should show the tooltip only on left side. In my page load buttons join with some questions which is comes from server. so If question has too long it comes second line. In this case failed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the placement of the tooltip from `left` to `right` so that the tooltip's placement doesn't put it outside of the viewable area.

```
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="tips my-tip2" data-placement="right" data-content="Second Popover content">
       Second Div Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhj9y7qa/1/).

Comment: I must show the tooltip in left side only. Because button comes whereever in my page.

Comment: @GokulKumar, in your original question, the tooltip **was already** showing on the left side...you just couldn't see it. If your requirement is both that the tooltip appear on the left side ***and*** the initiating element be on the left side of the screen, then what you're asking for is **impossible**.